# Targeting only the clicked item on a mapped component ( React quiz trivia App)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i'm trying to develop an App with React using the Open trivia Api. I have mapped a button component (using material ui) to show the different answers for each question. I'm struggling now to target only the clicked one to apply a css property: if the answer is correct should become green, else red. The problem is the fact that once i click, all button become red or green. I tried to store the index in a state and compare the real index, but it doesn't work. here is my code:
in the main APP.js

```
  const [clickedOne, setClickedOne] = useState({
    clickedIndex: null,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    grabData();
  }, []);

  const handleClick = (choice, ke) => {
    setChoice(choice);

    if (choice === data.correct_answer) {
      setIsCorrect(true);
    } else {
      setIsCorrect(false);
    }
    setClickedOne({ clickedIndex: ke });

    grabData();
  };
```

The mapped button inside the Render:

```
      {answers.map((answer, index) => {
          return (
            <ContainedButtons
              choice={handleClick}
              answer={answer}
              correct={data.correct_answer}
              isCorrect={isCorrect}
              key={index}
              id={index}
              clicked={clickedOne}
            />
          );
        })}
```

Inside the Button component:

```
const backStyle = () => {
    if (clicked === id) {
      if (isCorrect) {
        return "green";
      } else if (isCorrect === false) {
        return "red";
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Button
        style={{ backgroundColor: backStyle() }}
        value={answer}
        onClick={() => choice(answer, id)}
        variant="contained"
      >
        {decodeURIComponent(answer)}
      </Button>
```

When i check now inside the backstyle function if the clicked===id, now nothing happens anymore. Without that if check, i would have all buttons red or green. 
Thank you guys for the help!

Comment: React gives you SyntheticEvent object when you perform any action such as click/check etc. In that event you get the currentTarget. So why comparing with index when you can directly get the currentTarget and check only if that answer is correct you can apply style to that button. Hope it helps!!

Comment: I thought that react didn't like using Event property, that's why i passed the clicked answer as a parameter.

Comment: No. React loves playing with events, I mean that's why they created a Synthetic Event wrapper to give us information. No compiler will complain if you use events. And it will be easier for you to get the target and repaint it. You can read more about Synthetic events in React docs. Cheers!!

Comment: Thank you! So i can compare like if(clicked=e.target.id)?

Comment: Exactly @Robozombie. Upvote the answer so that it'll help others in future. Thanks

Comment: I tried, but i still have all the buttons triggered. Can i put on a codesandbox so you can have a look?

Comment: Sure. I can have a look

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-keldysh-wunrk?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I guess there's issue with your logic. First thing you're calling grabData() on click of option so it loads the another question, but at the same time you forget to reset your state for another question i.e. isCorrect and also i noticed that your render method get's invoked before your data is fetched.

Comment: I know that the logic is far of being perfect, but i was trying to tackle the button color first. Even with logic flaw, i should still see the only button clicked blinking for one second

Comment: If you check by adding console statements in your render and backStyle method you'll see it's been invoked multiple times which shouldn't be the case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have looked at your codesandbox demo, there are alot of other problems apart from the one your question is about.

First of all, each time you make a request to the API to fetch next question, you are making a request to get 10 questions instead of 1. API request URL contains a query parameter named `amount` which determines how many questions will be fetched on each request. Change its value to 1.

```
"https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=1&encode=url3986"
```

Secondly, there is a lot of unnecessary code and unnecessary use of `useState` hook. You only need 2 things to be stored in the state, `data` and `answers`

```
const [data, setData] = useState({});
const [answers, setAnswers] = useState([]);
```

Now, coming to the original problem of detecting which button is clicked and correctly updating its background color.

To achieve the desired functionality, take following steps:

1. create couple of CSS classes as shown below

   ```
   button.bgGreen {
     background-color: green !important;
   }

   button.bgRed {
     background-color: red  !important;
   }
   ```
2. pass a `handleClick` function from `App` component to `ContainedButtons` component. When a button is clicked, this click handler will be invoked. Inside the `handleClick` function, get the text and the button that was clicked using `Event.target` and depending on whether user answered correctly or not, add appropriate CSS class, created in step 1, on the button that was clicked.
3. Instead of using `index` as key for `ContainedButtons` in `map` function, use something that will be unique each time. This is needed because we want React to not re-use the `ContainedButtons` because if React re-uses the `ContainedButtons` component, then CSS classes added in step 2 will not be removed from the button.

Here's a working [codesanbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/summer-cloud-030x9?file=/src/App.js) of your app with the above mentioned steps.

In this demo, i have removed the unnecessary code and also changed the `key` of `ContainedButtons` inside `map` function to `key={answer.length * Math.random() * 100}`. You can change it to anything that will ensure that this key will be unique each time.

Comment: But how can i check if the event clciked has the same index of the parent? That's why i didn't want to use Event

Comment: @Robozombie can you create a codesandbox demo of your app and share the link?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-keldysh-wunrk?file=/src/App.js